# Convert json array to a java list object

Tags: java, json

I got an **json array** from server `response`:

```
[{"id":1, "name":"John", "age": 20},{"id":3, "name":"Tomas", "age": 29}, {"id":12, "name":"Kate", "age": 32}, ...]
```

I would like to use [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert the above json data to a Java `List<Person>` object. I tried the following way:

Firstly, I created a **Person.java** class:

```
public class Person{
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public long getId(){
     return id;
  }

  public String getName(){
     return name;
  }

  public int getAge(){
     return age;
  }
}
```

Then, in my service class, I did the following:

```
//'response' is the above json array 
List<Person> personList = gson.fromJson(response, List.class); 

for(int i=0; i<personList.size(); i++){
   Person p = personList.get(i); //java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to Person
}
```

I got Exception **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to Person** . How to get rid of my problem? I just want to convert the json array to a `List<Person>` object. Any help?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use a supertype token for the unmarshalling, so that Gson knows what the generic type in your list is. Try this:

```
TypeToken<List<Person>> token = new TypeToken<List<Person>>(){};
List<Person> personList = gson.fromJson(response, token.getType());
```

And iterate through the results as such:

```
for(Person person : personList) {
    // some code here
}
```